# macOS SecureTransport refuses to import a certificate accepted by OpenSSL

Tags: macos, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509, secure-transport

I'm trying to fix a failing test in the urllib3 open source Python project.

This test is called [test_client_no_intermediate](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/c41fa8c7ed8cb7315195dc15e67958754ea276d5/test/with_dummyserver/test_https.py#L91-L104) and tries to use a X.509 certificate called `client_no_intermediate.pem`. The goal is to fail with a "unknown CA" error. The test works as expected with OpenSSL: the import succeeds and the certificate is rejected.

However, on macOS with SecureTransport, the import fails with `Import/Export format unsupported.`. What's surprising is that it fails consistently on my machine with macOS 10.13.5 and Xcode 9.4.1 but [only fails intermittently in continuous integration](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/1409) with macOS 10.12 and XCode 8.3.

Here is the certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

OpenSSL happily decodes it:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -in client_no_intermediate.pem -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            16:18:03:39:88:74:98:94:84:82:04:58:68:34:36:56:38:11:77:20:30:91:79:80:57:62:86:21:35:44:86:22:70:52:60:46:28:18
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=FI, ST=dummy, O=dummy, OU=dummy, CN=SnakeOil/emailAddress=dummy@test.local
        Validity
            Not Before: May 12 18:34:26 2017 GMT
            Not After : Dec 19 18:34:26 2021 GMT
        Subject: C=FI, ST=dummy, O=dummy, OU=dummy, CN=SnakeOilClient/emailAddress=dummy@test.local
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (1024 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:9a:76:46:cf:2d:73:df:03:56:cd:8e:02:fd:17:
                    af:ab:54:bb:37:b9:97:5b:5d:e9:87:7f:5a:0a:91:
                    3e:2a:f6:ea:ee:65:34:02:4c:31:6f:bd:61:ea:df:
                    6a:fa:1b:c2:95:ec:c0:12:6a:b8:92:cf:e6:c8:82:
                    9c:75:7a:e6:44:3a:6c:2e:71:df:94:2e:cd:07:31:
                    d7:ea:a2:b4:5a:dc:cb:94:b4:ab:88:cd:88:90:bc:
                    2b:2f:ef:cf:15:a0:d2:a3:b3:e3:4d:30:87:b1:3b:
                    aa:7a:4b:d1:37:e9:c7:b6:b6:bc:de:04:29:a9:62:
                    68:b4:5a:87:ce:d1:b4:b0:9f
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:FALSE
            Netscape Comment:
                OpenSSL Generated Certificate
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                6D:EF:6B:79:2C:36:0B:BD:89:B8:65:69:73:EF:CB:FC:ED:A1:56:3C
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:9E:5B:6C:9E:E8:76:9A:3B:6A:A8:35:A4:D9:13:52:C0:2E:E7:8C:79

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         0e:52:69:de:e3:0a:c6:04:b6:86:00:8a:f8:96:55:e2:ab:17:
         1a:e6:7f:ad:c1:e0:ab:9a:a5:ad:f8:34:8b:be:be:c3:06:7a:
         7e:cd:d6:41:ef:b3:36:05:db:26:74:6f:88:cd:15:49:c4:94:
         04:cf:08:b9:c9:72:a2:f1:56:2e:fb:34:67:4a:62:10:bb:59:
         ec:a3:f0:ac:35:5f:e5:2e:72:9c:91:e7:25:21:be:b2:3e:0d:
         ea:ff:ad:be:da:46:0d:bd:52:de:e7:8b:42:6e:fd:30:65:ef:
         f6:99:9b:69:80:66:50:9d:18:48:49:eb:49:c5:b2:f7:40:6f:
         4e:7a
```

But SecureTransport fails on this specific certificate:

```
$ security verify-cert -c cacert.pem
Cert Verify Result: CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED
$ security verify-cert -c client_no_intermediate.pem
SecCertificateCreateFromData: Unknown format in import.
```

What is wrong in this certificate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing obviously "wrong" with the certificate is the serial number is 38 bytes long.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-4.1.2.2

> Given the uniqueness requirements above, serial numbers can be
> expected to contain long integers.  Certificate users MUST be able to
> handle serialNumber values up to 20 octets.  **Conformant CAs MUST NOT
> use serialNumber values longer than 20 octets.**

While there is also guidance that non-conformant CAs exist, it's possible that Apple put in a limit lower than 38 bytes.

That wouldn't explain intermittency, but having a certificate which doesn't look "conformant" is always asking for unreliability.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like that is the issue indeed, but I'm trying to generate the same certificate with a shorter serial number now before I can accept.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue! I used https://github.com/python-trio/trustme and a modified cryptography package to generate two certificates, and only the one with more than 20 bytes fails to import! Thank you again, that was incredibly useful. Accepted.